# How to add ManyToManyField in Existing django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a follwing two tables:

```
class Visit(models.Models):

    date_created            = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified           = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_started            = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_completed          = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    # Here i want to add ManyToManyField
    research                = ManyToManyField(ResearchProtocol) #Here i will write for adding the field

class ResearchProtocol(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField()
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title
```

For that i have written sql query :

```
CREATE TABLE "visit_visit_research" (
    "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "visit_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "visit_visit" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    "research_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "www_researchprotocol" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
    UNIQUE ("visit_id", "research_id")
)
;
```

When i execute this file the field is created somehow but when i open vist admin
and click to a particular id that leads to change form it gives me the following error:

```
http://localhost:8000/admin/visit/visit/20/

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /admin/visit/visit/20/
Exception Value: column visit_visit_research.researchprotocol_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...visit_research" ON ("www_researchprotocol"."id" = "visit_vis...
                                     ^
```

Somebody said that you need south and it cannot be done without south. Is that the only solution ? I am using Django 1.3.1, Python 2.7.2.

Can somebody guide me what mistake i am doing?
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've called your linking table `visit_visit_research`, and the field within it `research_id`, whereas Django is expecting `visit_visit_researchprotocol` and `researchprotocol_id` respectively.

Comment: Hi Daniel . You are write i made a that silly mistake in frustation.I also verified it by using python manage.py sql appname. Finally made it correct. I would like to ask one thing why django creates a foreign key after creating a ManyToManyField sql query . So finally we don't require south .I am quite nervous as i have add this field into the server and i don't want any problem there. Thanks Daniel

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I have modified the table models I used south and these commands to modify the structure and they always worked:

```
python manage.py convert_to_south "your_app"
python manage.py migrate "your_app"
```

You could try these and it should work, if you still have south installed.

Comment: Hi reos thanks for help. I manage without south but on my local only .I would like to ask that i have to apply the same procedure on the server too and i don't want any error there.So can you please tell me is it necessary to go for south.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know any alternative. It's what I've always tried and it always worked for me. If you doubt that it will work, then I might not suggest you try south. If I come onto another alternative I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much reos.I appreciate this !

Comment: Well i did not committed the code to the server yet but i have verified with python manage.py sql appname command the sql script and i believe that if i run that script at server it will run properly. In my local it is running fine